# Can Ubercart be adapted to print a letter?

Tags: theming, ubercart

When an order is received through [Ubercart](https://www.drupal.org/project/ubercart), the details can be viewed and printed, but can the *print order* option be expanded to do more? When I ship product, I like to **include a personalised letter** in addition to the standard order form.

Can I craft such a letter, so that it prints out after the order page, showing letterhead, date, customers address, and separate envelope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In D7 there's a 2 step process to this.

1. Copy **ubercart/uc_order/uc_order-invoice-page.tpl.php** to your current theme directory and flush your cache; this will let you create your own custom version of the the order template.
2. Add this snippet to your new template after `<?php print $content; ?>`; this will add some markup/CSS that will be rendered as a new page when treated as a printable document.

   ```
   <?php /* Print only from administration page*/ ?>
   <?php if(preg_match('/admin\\/store\\/orders\\/\\d+\\/invoice\\/print/', current_path()) == 1): ?>
     <div style="page-break-after: always;"></div>
     <div id="letter-region">
       <p>NEW PAGE</p>
     </div>
   <?php endif; ?>
   ```

If you're running a D6 site, it's a little more of pain (D6 UC ignores some theming conventions).

1. You'll need to copy **ubercart/uc_order/templates/uc_order-customer.tpl.php** to **ubercart/uc_order/templates/uc_order-custom.tpl.php**
2. Have a module define a new custom template via `hook_uc_invoice_templates()`: `function MYMODULE_uc_invoice_templates() { return array('custom'); }`
3. Set the new invoice in order setting page (**admin/store/settings/orders/edit/basic**).
4. Use the code in the above D7 example inside **uc_order-custom.tpl.php**. You'll have to modify since I don't think current_path() exists in D6. However, the same frontend logic still exists (add some extra markup in the template with CSS to generate a 2nd page).

There might be a better way to do this, but I've not touched D6 UC templating in a long time.